# How does Ubisoft Connect (formerly Uplay) track what games are installed?

Tags: ubisoft-connect

I feel like the question itself will make sense to anyone who knows the answer, but to expand a bit...

I am in the process of making a program that can allow me to monitor the size of my game libraries on my PC, relocated games between different drives, and archive them off on my local network. Steam has the most straightforward system with the app_manifest files. The Epic Game Store system holds all its current installed game info in a single file. I haven't been able to figure out how Ubisoft Connect does it.

I have checked the following areas:

- The Ubisoft Connect folders
- ProgramData, public AppData, and user specific AppData folders
- The registry

I can't find anywhere that it stores an obvious game ID to install path record. There are several files I have found that are short enough overall to coincide with my installed games count, but they are encoded in a non-obvious format, or encrypted.